# Stage only those files containing a specific change in Git

Tags: git

I want to upgrade to a newer version of a CMS whose development is tracked in Git. Since the CMS update is in the new year, every file gets the copyright date bumped from 2011 to 2012.

I could visually inspect and stage each file that just gets the copyright bump using git gui. However, it seems like I should be able to tell git to stage only those files whose only change is:

```
- * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
+ * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 - 2012, EllisLab, Inc.
```

There are a few thousand files that changed, but the vast majority of these received no other change than this specific line. I want to stage and commit this simple copyright date bump, then take a closer look at those files receiving more substantive changes.

This purpose could be accomplished by two possible means:

1. Stage and commmit only those files that just contain this change.
2. Stage and commit just this change from all files.

Is either possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be nice (but not necessary) if you could explain why you want to just stage those files.  Also, your wording is unclear if you want to just stage that content, or if you want to stage only files with that change, or only files with only that change.  Which is why if you explain in more detail, we can help you arrive where you want to end up.

Comment: Thanks. Just clarified purpose. Sorry for ambiguity on desired method - both work.

Comment: Interesting question! A starting point would be to look carefully at [`git add --patch`](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-add/) (random blog link, better ones to be found with googling) and see whether (1) you can access the individual patches in a script and (2) whether you can provide responses from a script.

Comment: Could you try using `git stash` to stash all your changes, then re-apply the copyright bump, add everything, commit, and then `git stash pop` to restore your changes?

Comment: So basically - stash everything, then find and sed to change all the copyright lines, commit that, then git stash pop to restore everything else? Will try that...

Comment: thx for the link @eykanal a preliminary read of the linked page and the man pages in question didn't turn anything else but I'm novice enough that I may well have missed something

Comment: Ok, so @KevinBallard's suggestion did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I recently had to do the exact thing for a Magento upgrade. 90% of the changes were just updated copyright lines. So I figured out the following "one-liner".

```
git diff -G '@copyright.*[Cc]opyright' --name-only | xargs -I {} sh -c 'FILE={} ; [ $(git diff -U0 -- $FILE | wc -l | tr -d " " | cut -f1-) -eq 7 ] && git add $FILE'
```

If you want to be safe and verify things first, change the last part to 'echo git add $FILE', so that it only prints out the command.

Comment: Holy Strube, thanks a lot. This was exactly what I needed. Damn Magento

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I've answered in reverse order, but...

## 2 Stage only those lines:

```
 git add --patch
```

It's a fairly manual method, though, so maybe this saves some time, allowing you to only review those with relevant change,

```
for i in $(gd -SYOURCHANGESTRING | sed -rn 's/^diff --git a\/(\S+).*$/\1/p'); do git add --patch "$i"; done
```

## 1 Stage ALL those files with changed string.

Something like this:

```
git diff -SYOURCHANGESTRING | sed -rn 's/^diff --git a\/(\S+).*$/\1/p' | xargs -n1 git add
```

Answer (score 0):

For mac users the following works:

```
git add `git diff -G 'YOUR_REGEX_GOES_HERE' --name-only`
```